# FakerPHP/Faker - Maximum retries of 10000 reached without finding a unique value

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-seeding, factories

https://fakerphp.github.io/#modifiers

There is a `1-1` relationship between `Detail` and `Video`.

This is my seeder of `Video` (I make 500 `Video`s):

```
Video::flushEventListeners();
Video::factory()->count(500)->create();
```

This is my factory of `Detail` (It is the only `unique()` I use in this factory):

```
$ids = Video::withTrashed()->select('id')->get()->pluck('id'); // They are 500

return [
    ...
    'video_id' => $this->faker->unique()->randomElement($ids)
];
```

Output:

```
OverflowException 

Maximum retries of 10000 reached without finding a unique value
```

Why does this problem arise if there are 500 different `Video`s values for also 500 `Detail`s?

I understand that there would be a problem if there were 100 `Video`s for 500 `Detail`s, **but this is not the case**

After the error, if I run **only** the `Detail` seeder it works, this is very rare:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=DetailSeeder
```

Comment: If `->randomElement()` is being called 500 times on 500 unique `id`s, by the 499th time, it would need to find the last remaining `id` without finding an already-used one. I'm no expert at odds, but it seems very possible that you don't get that 1/500 chance within the 10,000 tries Faker is limited to. A typical approach to this would be to shuffle an array, remove the first (or last) id, and use that, then repeat 500 times until the array is empty. I don't have a solution for you, but I think that explains _why_ you're facing this issue. If you generate say 1000+ ids, this might work 1st try.

Comment: When you say "this is the only unique you use in this factory" does this mean you use unique somewhere else as well? I am asking because I think unique is globally unique so other places would affect it. Sharing your video seeder might help clarify things. This happening by pure chance if everything else is working correctly is 0.0000002% so unlikely